# UDP sendto() function occasionally takes too long

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, udp, sendto

I’m using UDP function sendto(), According to the UDP protocol, the function should send/discard the datagram and then return immediately,
However, in my test, I found that in a LAN, when I sending a large number of data patckets(200M) continuously, most of the time consuming is less than 1ms, but sometimes more than 10ms, or even 20~30ms.
client.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define SIZE 1024 * 1024 * 200

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /*
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("needs params\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    int num = atoi(argv[1]);
    */
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(0);
    }
    /*
    int bufsize = 0;
    int len = sizeof(int);
    getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (void *)&bufsize, &len);
    printf("default: send buff = %d\n", bufsize);
    bufsize = bufsize * num;
    printf("bufsize change to %d\n", bufsize);
    setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (const void *)&bufsize, sizeof(int));
    bufsize = -1; //reset
    len = sizeof(int);
    getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (void *)&bufsize, &len);
    printf("after set, send buff = %d\n", bufsize);
    */
    
    struct sockaddr_in seraddr;
    seraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    unsigned short port = 49244;
    seraddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "43.82.153.211", &seraddr.sin_addr.s_addr);

    char buf[1400];
    memset(buf, 'g', sizeof(buf));
    long long size = SIZE;
    struct timeval before, after;
    double mseconds = 0;
    unsigned int count = 1;
    while(size > 0)
    {
        gettimeofday(&before, NULL);
        int err = sendto(fd, buf, 1400, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&seraddr, sizeof(seraddr));
        gettimeofday(&after, NULL);
        if (-1 == err)
        {
            perror("sendto");
            exit(0);
        }
        mseconds = 1000 * (after.tv_sec - before.tv_sec) + (double)(after.tv_usec - before.tv_usec) / 1000;
        printf("%d:  %-0.6f mseconds\n", count, mseconds);
        memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
        size -= 1400;
        count++;
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

log:

```
...
546:  0.074000 mseconds
547:  0.083000 mseconds
548:  0.041000 mseconds
549:  0.067000 mseconds
550:  0.072000 mseconds
551:  0.048000 mseconds
552:  7.541000 mseconds(Much higher than other values)
553:  0.082000 mseconds
554:  0.084000 mseconds
...
```

I want to know which cause this time consuming.

I found 2 parameters, sendbuf and SIOCSIFTXQLEN. Below is what I have tried:
(running on arm, kernel: linux-3.0.27)

1. default behaviour

```
# time ./client > client.log
real    0m 18.19s
user    0m 2.35s
sys     0m 4.78s
```

only print time>10ms(the same for all the following sample)

```
# time ./client_print_largethan_10ms > client_print_largethan_10ms.log
real    0m 17.88s
user    0m 0.50s
sys     0m 4.44s
```

2. set send buf * 8, the actual value is 16 times, The kernel doubles this value (to allow space for bookkeeping overhead)
   first, set the maximum allowed value of send buff size in system:

```
# sysctl -a | grep "net.core.wmem_"
net.core.wmem_max = 110592
net.core.wmem_default = 110592
# sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max=2211840
net.core.wmem_max = 2211840
# sysctl -a | grep "net.core.wmem_"
net.core.wmem_max = 2211840
net.core.wmem_default = 110592
```

then run the test

```
# time ./client_sndbuf_x 10 > client_sndbuf.log
real    0m 9.34s
user    0m 0.62s
sys     0m 4.63s
```

It takes less time, but there are still records which large that 10ms in the log.

3. set SIOCSIFTXQLEN * 10 with ioctl()
   from 1000 to 10000, then run again.

```
# time ./client_print_largethan_10ms 49244 > client_print_largethan_10ms_afterset_SIOCSIFTXQLEN.log
real    0m 17.82s
user    0m 0.49s
sys     0m 4.32s
```

No obvious change

```
# time ./client_sndbuf_x 10 > client_sndbuf.log
real    0m 17.84s
user    0m 0.55s
sys     0m 4.27s
```

even in this case, it takes longer.
I restored the SIOCSIFTXQLEN, and it takes 9 seconds again.

There seems to be some relationship between these two parameters. I don't want to completely eliminate time consuming, but I want to know how these time consuming are generated.
Thanks.

Comment: Linux is not a real-time OS. Delays may be caused by scheduler.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the NIC of your machine can only send 1 stream at a time, so if other processes are sending data at the moment, your data will end up in a queue for a while.